# Limit of google slide converting to/from ppt

Tags: google-docs-api

We have been seeing failure in uploading MS powerpoint file larger  than 100MB to Google slide.
We are using insert_file API    https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-uploads
The same ppt file would fail importing into google slide directly via google doc which it error out eventually with “server rejected“.  Separately, for exporting google slide to ppt, we also encounter random failure for file larger than 100mb. We think these are same issue mentioned in this doc [https://gsuitetips.com/tips/docs/google-docs-size-limitations/#:~:text=Presentations%20created%20in%20Google%20Slides,presentations%20converted%20to%20Google%20Slides](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/docs/google-docs-size-limitations/#:%7E:text=Presentations%20created%20in%20Google%20Slides,presentations%20converted%20to%20Google%20Slides). There is 100MB limit for slide.
Is there a solution or plan for a solution from google to this issue?
100MB is not that large. We are software provider for content management. User often has slides larger than that. The import/export is needed for customer to edit the slide because we are integrated with Google Drive as a source provider of content.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to an official documentation from [Files you can store in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603), it's also stated that 100 MB is the maximum size for presentations converted to Google Slides.

As for any plans or solutions, I've tried checking if there are similar [feature ideas](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191598%2B%20type:feature_request&p=1) that have already been requested, but unfortunately I haven't found any related requests being worked on. I'd suggest you check the [Missing features](https://developers.google.com/slides/support#missing_features) on Google Slides API.